# '::out' has not been declared

Tags: c++

Following is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=5, y=6;
    int out = x + y;

    {
        int out= 89;
        cout << :: out << "\n";
    }

    cout << out;
}
```

For which I got

```
error: ‘::out’ has not been declared                                                  
   12 |   cout << :: out << "\n";                                                                                                                 
      |              ^~~
```

EDIT: I was expecting it to print the variable `out`  whose value is 11 (like `nonlocal` in python) but instead I got the error. How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no global variable named `out` in the code shown. There are two local variables both named `out`, neither of which can be referred to as `::out`. You can fix this by giving different variables different names, and dropping `::`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, @songyanyao. Thanks for pointing out. But what if I want to access outer block's ```out``` instead of inner one (like ```nonlocal``` in python lang).

Comment: There is no syntax for that. Just give them different names.

Comment: There is no error message here stating that the 'scope resolution operator has not been declared'. You must quote error messages accurately, which also means you must *read* them accurately. This will also help prevent you from jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no global variable `out`, you have to declare a global variable outside the main or you can simply remove the scope resolution operator `::` and print the  value of `out`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 6;
    int out = x + y;
    {
        int out = 89;
        cout << out << "\n";
    }
    cout << out;
}
```

If you want to use global variable first change the name

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int Globalout;
int main()
{
    int x = 5, y = 6;
    Globalout = x + y;
    {
        int Localout = 89;
        cout << Localout << "\n";
    }
    cout << ::Globalout;
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Removing `::` would print only the current scope. There is no way to access outer scope that is not a global variable.

Comment: Yeah! I know but we can store `out` in a reference variable with a different name.

Comment: Please delete the part where you say *simply remove the scope resolution operator :: and print the value of out*. It is misguiding. It will print current scope `out` which is 89 and not outer scope `out` which is 11 and what the question has asked for.

Comment: You have to say that there is no way in C++ to access outer-scope local variable with same name. Except for giving a different name or creating a reference to outer variable with different name before inner variable.